# C# How may i replace \" with "

Tags: c#

I am trying to replace `\"` in a string with `"`, how may i do that?
I've tried using replace but i could not find a way to do it.

Ex:

```
string line = "This is a \"sample\" "
string replaced = "This is a "sample" ".
```

Thanks.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186949/discussion-on-question-by-jake-manet-c-how-may-i-replace-with).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because quotes are used to start and end strings (they are a type of control character), you can't have a quote in the middle of a string because it would terminate the string

```
string replaced = "This is a "sample" ";
/*
You can see from the syntax highlighting (red) that the string is being
detected as <This is a > and <sample> is black meaning it is detected as 
code (and will cause a syntax error)
*/
```

In order to put a quote in the middle of the string we escape it (escaping means to treat it as a character literal instead of a control character) using the escape character, which in C# is backslash.

```
string line = "This is a \"sample\"";
Console.WriteLine(line);
// Output: This is a "sample"

string literalLine = @"This is a ""sample""";
Console.WriteLine(literalLine);
// Output: This is a "sample"
```

The @ symbol in C# means I want this to be a literal string (ignore control characters), however quotes still start and end strings so in order to print a quote in a literal string you write two of them "" (that's how the language is designed)

Answer (score 0):

Case 1: If the value within the variable `line` is actually `This is a \"sample\"`, then you could do `line.Replace("\\\"", "\"")`.

If not:
`\"` is an escape sequence. it shows up as `\"` in the code, however when it compiles it would show up as `"` instead of the original `\"`.

The reason for escaping quotes is because the compiler cannot identify whether the quote is within another quote or not. Let's see your example:

`"This is a "sample" "`

is this `This is a` as one group, then an unknown token `sample`, then another quote ? or `This is a "sample"` all within a quote? We can take a guess by looking at the context, but compiler cannot. Hence, we use escape sequence to tell the compiler "I used this double quote character as a character, not the closing/opening of a string literal."

See Also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C

Answer (score -3):

You may try something like this:

```
String str = "This is a \"sample\" ";
Console.WriteLine("Original string: {0}", str);
Console.WriteLine("Replaced: {0}", str.Replace('\"', '"'));
```

Comment: Please read up on escape sequences. `\\` is an escape character in C like languages used to print control characters as literals.

Answer (score -3):

Desired output : This is a sample

Given string : `"This is a \"sample\""`

The problem: you have escape characters protecting the double quotes from being interpreted.  the `\` escape character is an instruction to use a quotation mark literally instead of using it to indicate a break in the string.   This means the actual string value is `"This is a "sample""` when served as output.

The answer removing the `\` may work, but it makes for smelly code because removing an escape character in this way can make it unclear what you intend and prevents you from escaping *any* character.

Removing the `"` might work, though it prevents use of any quotes and some IDEs might leave the escape character behind to ruin your day.

We want one specific target, the quotes around "sample".

```
            string sample = "This is a \"sample\"";
            List<string> sampleArray = sample.Split(' ').ToList(); // samplearray is now split into ["This", "is", "a", "\"sample\""]
            var x = sampleArray.FirstOrDefault(t => t == "\"sample\"");  //isolate our needed value
            if (x != null) //prevent a null reference in case something went wrong and samplearray wasnt as expected
            { 
                var index = sampleArray.IndexOf(x); //get the location of the value we just picked
                x = x.Replace("\"", string.Empty); //replace chars
                sampleArray[index] = x; //assign new value to the list

            }
            return String.Join(" ", sampleArray); //return the string joined together with spaces.
```

Answer (score -4):

Try this:

```
string line="This is a \"sample\" " ;
replaced =line.Replace(@"\", "");
```

Comment: There is no `\\` in the original string.

Comment: This will for sure work - as it really does **nothing** to the line value

Comment: The Output should be "This is a "sample"". The Code deliveres "This is a sample". Thats not what he expected !

Comment: @Glowhollow Are you really sure? [.net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/loUnHo) tells us a different story

Comment: Please read up on escape sequences. `\\` is an escape character in C like languages used to print control characters as literals.